# MVC 5 Auto fill email textbox on userid textbox change

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two textboxes like this :
User id = 552
email = blank

**how can I make email textbox to be auto fill on User id change to be :**

email = 552@school.com

So IF I change User id the email changes directly before post.

all users will have email at **school.com** just include their user id before @

I tried JavaScript but can't add @school.com as text
any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the String concat() method.

Something like this:

```
userID.concat('@school.com');
```

Comment: anything after @ coms with red error line and says dose not exist in the current context.

Comment: The problem using @ in html if we put it anywhere considered as command to be continued I can't use it as text.

Comment: Yeah first of all u need to convert the userID into an string. For example: userID.toString().concat('@school');